# How do I use my screen calibration profile in Lightroom under wine?

Tags: lightroom, color-management, linux, open-source

I have a .icc monitor profile from my colorhug, which I use with GIMP and geeqie. I have xiccd running which sets the X11 _ICC_PROFILE atom to point at my .icc file.

All the guides I've seen for Lightroom under Wine say you have to give it an sRGB icm file in the right path, e.g.:

```
sudo apt install colord-data
mkdir -p ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/spool/drivers/color/
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/spool/drivers/color/
cp /usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc 'sRGB Color Space Profile.icm'
```

This seems to be a requirement for Lightroom to work at all. But still the colours in Lightroom were all different from GIMP and geeqie (with colour management on), and in fact looked closer to the colours when I click the "turn off colour management" button in geeqie (the non-managed colours are quite over-saturated).

From what I can tell, there is no GUI to select a *screen* profile in Lightroom (there's a soft-proofing GUI for printing etc., but nothing for monitors), it should just pick up the "system" profile. So I tried overwriting the sRGB.icm file with my colorhug.icc and restarting Lightroom, but that had no effect on the colours :( And I guess Wine is not correctly configuring the icc file pointed to by X11 _ICC_PROFILE.

So how do I get Lightroom under wine to use my colorhug.icc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I noticed there were some extra files in `.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/spool/drivers/color/`, some of which I guessed were from my experimenting, but I wasn't sure, so on a whim I tried removing them all and restarting Lightroom, and then I saw a file being created called `26d6cc1d628462ebbe35d4d50d34c8bfa086b9c7.icm`. So I closed Lightroom, and overwrote that strangely-named file with my colorhug.icc, and it worked, the colours now look the same in GIMP, geeqie and Lightroom :-)

So the solution is: delete all the files in that folder, and see what file is created by Lightroom on startup, then overwrite that.

EDIT: Actually, if you use it with a new monitor, don't delete *all* the files in that folder, let the `sRGB Color Space Profile.icm` stay. That file is used when LR can't scrape a profile from the monitor itself (some monitors come with built-in profiles), so if you try a new monitor, you'd better have that sRGB file there, or LR may show the pictures as big gray blobs and such (until you turn on soft-proofing, where it'll use a different profile).